# Why can't my site access a linked JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript

I run a  sub-site at my work, and while my live site is on the same "main server" as the company's main site, my dev environment is hosted on a separate server.

For some reason my dev site is unable to access a specific JavaScript file that is hosted on the "main server". All of the other JavaScript files, like jQuery, and jQueryTools can be accessed, but `main.js` cannot. My only guess would be because it is a custom JavaScript file created by our head web developer, but I don't know why that would make a difference. (**Cross-site scripting limitations?**)

I link to it just like I do with all the other JavaScript files, right after our main wrapper (it's the 3rd from the bottom):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ui/2009/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ui/2009/js/jquerytools/1.2.2/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ui/2009/js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ui/2009/js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ui/2009/js/jquery.jgfeed-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ui/2009/js/hr.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you look at the request and error in the browser related to this script fetching ?

Comment: Not enough information. What does something like Firebug show? 404 error? It's an internal system, so there's nothing for anyone else to look at: have you asked the server managers about file permissions?

Comment: No, but what is the best way to do that?

Comment: In google chrome use Developer Tools (F12), go to Network tab, refresh the website, see the status of main.js file. Most likely it's just a permission issue.

Comment: Actually found out that my assistant copied the JS file and is hosting it on our dev server. So it doesn't have anything to do with cross-site linking.

Comment: Do you have a min.js file in ( ui/2009/js/) location. ui/2009/js/min.js is your local file structure.

Comment: Copy min.js file in ui/2009/js/ location

Comment: Its weird though because I checked and its being retrieved fine but its not showing in the script tab in firebug. Why would this be?

Comment: In Chrome Network Tab, what http response (status) you have for your main.js ?

Comment: You say "my dev site is unable to access a specific JavaScript file". How do you know?  Is it possible it’s being loaded, all right, but the code either doesn’t compile, or it contains an error which prevents it from running?

Comment: It has a 304 @rayfranco, which make me think that Martijn is probably right. I will check the code and report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To troubleshoot follow these steps:

- Check whether the file *ui/2009/js/main.js* is actually in that
  location, if so be sure it doesn't have uppercase characters (the
  server OS may be case sensitive)
- Check whether the file *main.js* has the same permissions (i.e. chmod) as the other .js files (e.g. 755)
- Check whether the file main.js is actually accessed (how do you know the file is
  not accessed from your page in the dev server? It may be accessed but not working because of variable
  conflicts with the .js you previously load, for instance). To do so,
  you can a) check the server logs and see if you have a "not found"
  error referred to the main.js file b) in main.js delete temporarily all
  the content and print some simple output (either to screen with
  *document.write* or to the javascript console with *console.log*)